# How can I set up a database to work with GIT that will deploy to Heroku?

Tags: git, mongodb, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon EC2 as my dev environment. I do all the coding through SSH.

My app needs a database. I'm using Node.JS. I'm guessing I need mongoDB, but I'm open to other options. The app is a simple note taking app, but I want it to be able to scale. And I'd like the ability to save images in notes. There also needs to be a note searching function.

I ran out of space on my Amazon EC2 when I tried running mongoDB. How can I set up mongo on Amazon, and when I do:

```
git push heroku master
```

I want the database to be working on heroku as well.

How do I do this? Do I just install mongoDB as a service on heroku and assume everything transfers over? Do I need to buy MongoDB from the Amazon Marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think one solution would be to set up the db on heroku and whenever you'd like the db on heroku to mirror your amazon db, then just dump the amazon db and restore the dump to the heroku db.

I don't think there's really any sort of functionality built into heroku that would allow you to push your code to heroku and perform a one-way sync of the data in the amazon db to the heroku db in one line.